# The sequence I am calculating (hailstone) is printing twice when it needs to print once

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop, collatz

So in the main of my program there is a section where I call on the hailstone function to answer a question in a print statement.
Instead of it printing the sequence once, it is printing it twice and I don't know why or how to fix it. 
Is there a way to fix this and remove the print statement from the function next(n)?
Also, I wanted to know if my comments seem okay?
I have a hard time writing decent contracts so any tips and critiques on those would be great. But the main thing is getting the hailstone sequence to print once, not twice.

```
// Program hailstone takes a number and gives a sequence of 
// numbers starting with the input(n). The sequence alogrithm
// is (3n+1) then the next number is the previous divided by two.


#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

// The function next(n)takes an integer value n and 
// returns the number that follows n in a hailstone sequence. 
// For example: next(7) = 22 and next(22) = 11.

int next(int n)
{
  if (n > 1)
  {            
    if ((n % 2) == 0 )
    {
      n = n / 2;
    }
      else
      {
        n = 3 * n + 1;
      }   
     printf("%i ",n); 
  }          
  return n;
}

// The function hailstone reads int n and 
// prints its entire hailstone sequence.

void hailstone(int n)
{
  while(n>1)
  {
    n = next(n);
  }
} 

// Parameters: int length, int n
// Uses next function, to calculate the length of the sequence.
int length(int n)
{
    int length = 1;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n = next(n);
        ++length;
    }
    return length;
} 

int main()
{
  int n; 

  printf("What number shall I start with? ");
  scanf("%i", &n);

  printf("The hailstone sequence starting at %i is:", n);
  hailstone(n);

  printf("\nThe length of the sequence is: %i", length(n));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C code in a C++ program. If you are doing C, use the C compiler. If you are doing C++, use C++, not C disguised as C++.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the print statement in next. Put it in hailstone.
It's showing up twice because it's printed once from hailstone and once from length.